# How can I discover if a program is running from command line or from web?

Tags: python, command-line, cgi

I have a python script and I wanna know if the request
is from web or from command line. How can I do this?

Answer (score 9):

When run as a CGI, environment variables such as `REQUEST_METHOD` will be present. If not, then you're not running in a CGI environment.

You can check this like this:

```
import os
if os.getenv("REQUEST_METHOD"):
    print("running as CGI")
else:
    print("not running as CGI")
```